# Language; math vs maths

Tags: word-usage, american-english, british-english, mathematics, transatlantic-differences

I've heard of the term "maths" used by my UK friends, I am from the US and I use the word "math".

***Is "maths" grammatically correct?***

For me, it rolls off the tongue oddly;

- My maths teachers gave us a test.
- I've to study maths today.
- Maths is one of my least favorite subjects.
- Maths is part of everyday life.
- Did you finish your maths homework today?

Is it just me? Because of how I was taught to use "math" instead of "maths"?

Comment: I think it is just what you're used to. Would you find "My physics teachers gave us a test", "I've to study physics today", "Physics is one of my least favorite subjects" etc. etc. equally odd? It's just what you're used to. I spent three years in linguistics learning to appreciate the beauty of different dialects and forms of language - and learning not to insist that my way is *correct* - and, in my head, I still go "math**s**" every time I hear people say "math" :P

Comment: I've always thought that if you go with "maths" it should be conjugated in the plural, i.e. "maths are hard". They do it in French...

Answer (score 7):

There's no "correct" in this situation without the nation of use.  It is "correct" in the UK to say **maths** and "correct" in the US to say **math**. It's a [regional](https://www.englishclub.com/vocabulary/british-american.htm) word, much like the use of:

- biscuit vs cookie
- bonnet vs hood
- boot vs trunk

Plus, if you think about the full word, **maths** sort of makes more sense... the word is "mathematic**s**", after all.

Answer (score 2):

American English varies (especially in it's uses of *z* vs *s*), and this is one of the ways it does so. Whilst over here in the UK it's (officially<sup>1</sup>) "maths" with an "s", American English has it without the "s".

If you're interested, here's the [Ngram data](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=math%2Cmaths&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cmath%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BMath%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bmath%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMATH%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cmaths%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmaths%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMaths%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMATHS%3B%2Cc0) on the two:

[image: Ngram data]

It looks like the American version is used more, but then again:

[image: Ngram data]

The American version of this word is used far more than the UK version with an "s".

So, in a nutshell, both are correct, it just depends what version of English you're using.

---

<sup>1: I'm not sure if it's said this way in practice: I've heard both said.</sup>